# Unable to install Miniconda on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: miniconda, macos-big-sur

I installed conda successfully with Miniconda on macOS Mojave version 10.14.3 but when I tried to do the same installation on macOS Big Sur version 11.2.3, the installation failed and the reason was not clear. I used the Miniconda2 MacOSX 64-bit pkg installer available on https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html.

[Here is a screenshot of the error message from the installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koREG.png)

Can someone please tell me what the possible reason could be behind this error and how I can successfully install conda?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Installation

1. Try bash installer

python 3.8 [Miniconda3 MacOSX 64-bit bash](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh)

python 2.7 [Miniconda2 MacOSX 64-bit bash](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh)

2. Navigate to the downloaded location form the terminal
3. Run the *bash shell* Copy&paste the command

```sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

4. Approve the all terms when it ask type **yes**
5. Close the terminal and open new one and Check the version

```sh
conda -V or Conda --version
```

valaaaaaa

### Alternative Try Silent mode installation

> DOCS [miniConda Installation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.1/user-guide/install/macos.html#)

### Add path Variable

- Add PATH environment variable

```sh
export PATH="/Users/my-user-name/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```